# JedisCluster Replication and EVAL

Tags: lua, redis, jedis, redis-cluster

I know that Jedis (and other client libs) can select an appropriate **shard** to execute the Lua script. However what I cannot find is how the master-slave nodes are used after.
Say I have multiple Lua scripts and part of them does writes, another part - reads. How does Jedis know whether it should be executed on master or slave considering slaves are read-only?

Does it always send `EVAL` commands to master even for read-only scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JedisCluster does not support Slaves as of now.

ReadOnly access to Slaves is [in development](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/pull/1789)

You may try to select slave nodes manually like examples [here](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/issues/988)

Answer (score 2):

Jedis sends all commands to master nodes in cluster mode. By all, I mean all sorts of Redis commands, not only `EVAL` commands.

Jedis *may* use slave nodes, but it's only during internal cluster configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Isn't this very performance-killing? I'd still would use replicas for HA, but reading from them would be nice too. Can you also provide a link for me confirming this behavior?